# The NavSat_transform_node publish topic(/odometry/gps) but no msgs received

Tags: ros2, robot-localization

I am trying to fuse IMU(mpu6050) and gps(Neo7m) modules. I used madgwick filter from [imu_tools](https://github.com/CCNYRoboticsLab/imu_tools) package for imu. I have a problem with navsat_transform_node that publish the topic (navsat_transform_node) but no messages were provided.

My rqt_graph is as follow:
[image: rqt_graph]

When I echo topic of imu:
[image: imu_topic]

(frame id : imu_frame_bridge)

And my gps topic shows:
[image: gps_topic]

my launch file(ekf_global.launch.py) is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
package_dir = get_package_share_directory('navfuse')
config_file = os.path.join(package_dir, 'config', 'ekf_global.yaml')

use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')

return LaunchDescription([
    DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'use_sim_time', default_value='false',
        description='Use clock topic (from bagfile) if true'),


    Node(
        package='tf2_ros',
        executable='static_transform_publisher',
        name='map_link',
        output='screen',
        arguments=['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'map', 'odom']
    ),
    Node(
        package='tf2_ros',
        executable='static_transform_publisher',
        name='odom_link',
        output='screen',
        arguments=['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'odom', 'base_link']
    ),

    Node(
        package='tf2_ros',
        executable='static_transform_publisher',
        name='bl_gps',
        output='screen',
        arguments=['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'base_link', 'gps_link']
    ),
    # EKF node for global odometry
    Node(
        name='ekf_global_odom',
        package='robot_localization',
        executable='ekf_node',
        parameters=[config_file,
                    {'use_sim_time': True}],
        output = 'screen',
        # Subscriptions (in yaml):
        #   odom0: odometry/gps (from navsat node)
        #   odom1: base_controller/odom
        #   imu0:  imu/data
        # Publishes odometry/global
        remappings=[('/odometry/filtered', '/odometry/global')]
        
    ),

    # Turn GPS fix into odometry message for EKF
    Node(
        name='navsat_transform_node',
        package='robot_localization',
        executable='navsat_transform_node',
        # yaw_offset - corrects to make IMU read 0 when facing East
        # magnetic_declination - see http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag-web
        # zero_altitude - pretends the world is flat
        # use_odometry_yaw - false, use IMU yaw
        parameters=[{'yaw_offset': 0.0,
                     'magnetic_declination_radians': 0.0,
                     'broadcast_cartesian_transform': True,
                     'zero_altitude': True,
                     'publish_filtered_gps': True,
                     'frequency': 10.0,
                     'use_odometry_yaw': False}],
        output = 'screen',                                                            
        # Subscribes to imu/data, gps/fix, odometry/global
        # Publishes gps/filtered, odometry/gps
        remappings=[('/odometry/filtered', '/odometry/global'),
                    ('/imu','/imu/data'),
                    ('/gps/fix','/fix')]
)
])
```

and my config file (ekf_global.yaml) is:

```
ekf_global_odom:
ros__parameters:
two_d_mode: true
odom_frame: odom
base_link_frame: base_link
world_frame: map
map_frame: map

two_d_mode: true
publish_tf: true

frequency: 50.0

odom0: /odometry/gps
odom0_config: [true,  true,  false,   # x,   y,   z
               false, false, false,   # r,   p,   w (yaw)
               false, false, false,   # dx,  dy,  dz
               false, false, false,   # dr,  dp,  dw
               false, false, false]   # ddx, ddy, ddz
odom0_differential: false
odom0_queue_size: 10

# odom1: /base_controller/odom
# odom1_config: [false, false, false,   # x,   y,   z
#                false, false, false,   # r,   p,   w (yaw)
#                true,  true,  true,    # dx,  dy,  dz
#                false, false, true,    # dr,  dp,  dw
#                false, false, false]   # ddx, ddy, ddz
# odom1_differential: false
# odom1_queue_size: 10

# (note this is not raw IMU, but output from madgwick filter)
imu0: /imu/data
imu0_config: [false, false, false,   # x,   y,   z
              true,  true,  true,    # r,   p,   w (yaw)
              false, false, false,   # dx,  dy,  dz
              true,  true,  true,    # dr,  dp,  dw
              true,  true,  true,]   # ddx, ddy, ddz
imu0_differential: false
imu0_queue_size: 10
imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true
```

The navsat_transform_node show:
[image]

My question is that for fusing the imu and gps, frame_ids have to be imu_link and gps_link?

and how can I get rtk_gps for odometry?

Sorry for the basic question, I am new in ros2.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Just so I understand your problem, `navsat_transform_node` is not publishing any output?

You have a bunch of problems with your config in general:

1. You are telling your EKF instance that it is responsible for publishing the `map`->`odom` transform (you have `publish_tf` set to *true* and have your `world_frame` set to the same value as `map_frame`), but then you also have a `static_transform_publisher` publishing an identity transform from `map`->`odom`. You'll want to get rid of that static transform publisher.
2. Your IMU data is in the frame `imu_frame_bridge` but I don't see any transform provided from that frame to your base frame. This is probably your biggest issue.
3. (Not critical) You have `two_d_mode` set to *true*, but are attempting to fuse 3D variables like roll, pitch, and Z acceleration into your state estimate in the EKF. Those will be ignored.
4. In general, the combination of accleration + position is probably not going to work out well for you. You'll want some kind of velocity reference for your EKF state estimate. I see you have one, but it's commented out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. For no.1 I will readjust the tf frames names. and for no.2 the imu_frame_bridge comes from the madgwick filter from imu_tools package, I found no such a frame name in that package. For no.3 I just want to visualization for mapviz , so twod_d_mode is also fine for me.  No(4) give me to try in difference way. I am trying to use robot_localization just using imu and gps. I think I need to create velocity reference for kinematics from one of these sensors. ( the commented velocity reference was nothing because I don't have odometry sensor) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hello sir, it's me again. I think the problem is from the geographiclib that convert wgs84 to local cartesian coordinate.  In navsat_transform.cpp ( line no 849)```    gps_local_cartesian_.Forward(
      msg->latitude,
      msg->longitude,
      msg->altitude,
      cartesian_x,
      cartesian_y,
      cartesian_z);```  doesn't work if I use altitude as 0.0. But it work when I put the non-zero positive values.

Comment: Can you file a report on the project GH page? Please provide a detailed description there of what is not working, along with specific values for that method ^ that you believe are not working.

In the meantime, can you please accept the answer?